# Laravel Custom Auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Here i do the Login Validation

```
$LoginData   = Input::except(array('_token')) ;
if(Auth::attempt($LoginData)) 
{
    return 'success';
}
```

My Table is different so, here i change the table name in `auth.php`

```
'table' => 'administrators'
```

But I have the dropdown to choose for the usertype.

So how can i choose the tables for Authentication according to the usertypeinput.

i.e., Table may be administrators or parents or employees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether Laravel supports the change of auth table name on fly or not. I can suggest you a quick solution.

According to generalization theory of database design, you should store same type of information to one entity set. And according to specialization theory, if entity set can have various types of information for each entity, break them down into sub entity sets.

**Suggestion:**

- Create `user_types` table with column `id` & `name` (store user type names here)
- Create table `users` with 4 columns `id`, `email/username`, `password` & `user_type_id` (`user_type_id` is foreign key references `id` of `user_types`)
- Create 3 separate tables named `administrators`, `parents` or `employees`. All 3 tables should have one column `user_id` which is a foreign key references `users` table.
- Create relationship in model
- After a user login, you can determine which type of user he/she is from the `user<->user_type` relation
- You can get rid of the usertype dropdown from login page view now (You were disclosing some important information (3 user types) about your application to the whole planet, isn't it harmful for your application?)

**More info about generalization & specialization:**
[Generalization, Specialization and Aggregation](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/generalization-and-specialization.php)

Comment: Thanks, I shall make it use.  But i also need to know whether i want to change the auth table name on the fly

Comment: I will let you know if I can find any way. Thanks.