# Laravel Authenticating Users from 4 tables according to the input

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have totally 4 User Tables Namely

```
1. admin
2. Employee
3. Parent
4. Guardian
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#authenticating-users

For the test i tried with the users table as laravel suggests

I will get the `usertype, username and password` from the view to the controller

I read [Authentication with 2 different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18785754/4047397) But how can i do that in my case,

Is it possible to send the table with a parameter or

Is there any other way to do this. (I don't want to have all the users in single table)

Comment: This might help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656636/laravel-custom-auth/27669864#27669864

Comment: Why are you against having all users in a single table? They are all users, after all.